# VBA remove string by a specific character

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I have a

```
String str = "abc#daso.xlx".
```

I want to remove all characters in front of "#" so

```
str -> "#daso.xlx" .
```

I can't use Left or Right function because the length of the string in front of "#" can be changed. I'm thinking to use Split() method but it would be the last choice if I can't find any others ways. I just don't want to use Array in VBA.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of mid and instr

```
pos = InStr(yourString, "#")
newString = Mid(yourString, pos)
```

The first line finds the position of the first # in your string. The second asigns the substring from that position to the end of your string to a new string.

Comment: VBA questions are on topic for [su] - although more complicated ones are better off at [so]

Comment: oh I didn't know InStr return the index . Can I ask 1 more question ? what would have happened to the first line if my string don't contain "#" . Will it pop up error message or will it return some others value ? Thankks Sathya anw.

Comment: InStr will return 0 if String2 isn't inside String1 (assuming the form InStr(String1, String2). As VBA strings aren't 0-indexed, checking if InStr returns 0 is a good way to check a few situations when passed only 2 strings. As well as String2 not being in String1, InStr returns 0 when: String1 is "" or Nothing and String2 is not found.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
str$ = "abc#daso.xlx"

dim i%

i=instr(str, "#")

if i > 0 then str = mid(str, i)
```

Comment: You've effectively just repeated another answer.